# Siloxane condensation mechanism

Tags: reaction-mechanism

I want to formulate the condensation reaction mechanism for the formation of siloxane links.

[image: Siloxane formation]

I don't see how to express it as an addition-elimination reaction, because even though the silicone atom is positively polarized, it cannot form a fifth bond that would result from a nucleophilic attack by the other silanol. Is it a concerted reaction?

Any input is helpful, so no limit on conditions.

Any key publications?

Comment: Under what conditions? Acid or basic?

Comment: Note - silanols SiHnOH4-n such as drawn are highly unstable

Comment: @Waylander any conditions that you know the mechanism for :) Also, thanks for the note on stability; I understand that SiHnO4-n forms *in situ* from silyl chlorides.

Comment: If you google "Silanol condensation mechanism" one of the first hits is The Journal of Non-Crystalline Solids vol 100 (1998) 31-50 by CJ Brinker. The PDF is freely available and discusses acid and base-catalysed condensations at length